# Interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{\ln(n)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, absolute-convergence

> What is the interval of convergence of this series or for what values of $x$ does it converge?
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{\ln(n)}$$

I tried the ratio and root test but they were inconclusive, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have this formula correct?

Comment: Where is i in the equation

Comment: I have two points of confusion: (1) you index your sum by $i$, but $i$ does not appear in the summands at all; is there a typo? and (2) the sum is finite, hence there is no issue of convergence; did you mean for the sum to be finite?

Comment: Also, the term "interval of convergence" is generally applied to power series, and this isn't a power series.

Comment: $\sum_{\color{blue}{i}=0}^n x^{\ln(n)}$

Comment: Sorry the summation from n=1 to infinity

Comment: What values of x does the series converge ?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series+x%5E%7Bln+n%7D+from+n%3D1to+infinity

Comment: Go to that website

Comment: @fareed Can you please edit your question to accurately reflect its intent?

Answer (score 13):

The series is only defined for $x > 0$.  Under that assumption, $x^{\ln n} = n^{\ln x}$, so by the $p$-series test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\ln x}$ converges if and only if $\ln x < -1$, or $x \in (0, e^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

> If you allow me to use Wolfram alpha

All those tests are inconclusive

And it is converging if,
$$\ln |x| +1\lt 0$$

We can write
$$x^{\ln n}$$
$$e^{\ln n ×\ln x}$$
$$n^{\ln x}$$
This is the famous reimann zeta function,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$$
Where $s=-\ln x$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{-\ln x}}$$

Here is the proof

http://planetmath.org/PTest

Comment: The question is how you get this answer ?

Comment: Well it's not Riemann function.  Zeta function looks like this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^s$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Thank you, corrected.

Comment: Whatever it was almost the same